# Search View disappearing (icon)

Tags: android, searchview

I have an interesting problem - though maybe it is the expected behavior? I have a SearchView in my tool bar, which functions just fine till I enter a search then close it, at which time the search icon disappears and the ability to do another search is lost.

This behavior only happens when the search query is initiated - so if I enter search text, clear the search, then close it, the icon is there. But if I close it with data in it, then the Icon disappears. It is not the text color - I have clicked away and nothing seems to be there.

Here are some pictures of what I am talking about:

1. Search is there:

[image]

2. Enter search, query:

[image]

3. Close SearchView, icon gone

[image]

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/library_forms_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:title="refresh"/>

</menu>
```

The code looks like this:

```
import android.widget.SearchView;

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    mMenu = menu; // remember so we can get to later.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.library_forms, menu);

    (removed some code not related to this)

    // Implementing ActionBar Search inside a fragment
    MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    sv = new SearchView(getActivity());

    // If we are on a Phone, make the search an icon, otherwise show it all
    if (GlobalState.getInstance().isTwoPane == true) {
        sv.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }
    else {
        sv.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    }
    sv.setFocusable(false);

    // modifying the text inside edit text component
    int id = sv.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) sv.findViewById(id);
    textView.setHint("Form or Reference Number");
    textView.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    // Change the Icon color
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        int searchButtonId = sv.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
        ImageView searchButton = (ImageView) sv.findViewById(searchButtonId);
        searchButton.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
    }

    // implementing the listener
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            if (s != null && s.trim().length() > 0)
            {
                searchFilter = s;
                // Delay the lookup by 800 ms
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // do some stuff here...
                    }
                }, 800);

            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            // If the string is empty, reload the form
            if (newText == null || newText.trim().length() == 0)
            {
                searchFilter = null;
                // do some stuff here...
                // Hides the soft keyboard
                sv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                sv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                onQueryTextSubmit(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    item.setActionView(sv);
}
```

Comment: You can try creating an item resource like the refresh icon and add attribute app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" to it.

Comment: @NovoLucas Thanks. I was looking at that too wondering why it hadn't been implemented in the XML itself. I will give it whirl and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was this code:

```
        // do some stuff here...
        // Hides the soft keyboard
        sv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Which hid the keyboard and the icon.